# Need help with SQL ORDER BY

Tags: php, sql, mysql, select, sql-order-by

I have a table of contacts which has `name` and `default_name` columns among others.

**Contact name** is `name`, unless `name=NULL` and then it is `default_name` (which cannot be `NULL`).

I would like to order my selection by **contact name**.

For example:

```
contact_id          name          default_name
----------          ----          ------------
    1               Dave             David
    2                                Misha
    3                                Alex
    4            Brother Leon        Leon
```

should become:

```
contact_id          name          default_name
----------          ----          ------------
    3                                Alex
    4            Brother Leon        Leon
    1               Dave             David
    2                                Misha
```

How would I achieve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(name,default_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
ORDER BY (IF(name IS NOT NULL, name, default_name))
```

SQLMenace's solution is better. Leaving this in place to show how to use IF() in ORDER clauses.

mySQL Reference: [Control Flow Structures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

details differ depending on the DBMS, but the general idea is to ORDER BY IFNULL(name, default_name) for appropriate choice of the function IFNULL. The semantics of IFNULL are that it's the first value unless it's null, and then it's the second value. Most DBMSes know it by about that name.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

Comment: Apparently COALESCE is another name that function goes by.

Comment: +1, better to link 5.1 documentation though - 4.1 is rather dated: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

Comment: Yes but COALESCE  is ANSI standard, ISNULL() is another proprietary one..used by Sybase and SQL Server.  Oracle uses nvl()

Comment: Notice: the question tags MYSQL, so a MYSQL answer is suitable.

Comment: Yes, but ANSI syntax is generally preferred for sake of portability.  There're lots out there who think that SQL is the same on all databases, and are quick to find that's not the case.  A `CASE` expression evaluating on each column being null would be the next option after `COALESCE` for this question...